# Numeric validation in Commons Lang

Tags: java, apache-commons-lang

While using the `org.apache.commons.lang.math.NumberUtils.isNumber(String str)` function, I see that passing a string like `"1f"` passes validation while passing `"1a"` fails.

What kind of alphabets are allowed here?

Comment: 1f(1.0 Float) is regular Java language and 1a not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/math/NumberUtils.html#isNumber%28java.lang.String%29):

> Valid numbers include hexadecimal marked with the `0x`
>   qualifier, scientific notation and numbers marked with a type
>   qualifier (e.g. 123L).

`1f` means the float number 1.

Comment: But 1a is a valid hex number. So why it fails?

Comment: 0x1a is hex need the 0x (if im not mistaken)

Answer (score 4):

Jumping on the bandwagon...

[image]

Answer (score 2):

the `1f` is taking the 1 as a float.

`"1a"` won't be considered as a hexadecimal value because it needs the `0x` in front of it,

ex: "`0x1a`"